# Задача по егэ (паскаль)

Tags: pascal, алгоритм

Готовясь к экзамену по информатике (егэ). Мне попалась такая задача:

> На вход программе подаются сведения о сотрудниках некоторой
>   организации. В первой строке сообщается количество сотрудников N,
>   которое не меньше 5, но не превосходит 1000, каждая из следующих N
>   строк имеет следующий формат:
> <Фамилия> <Должность> <Стаж> <Оклад>
>   <Премия>,
>
> где:
>
> <Фамилия> - строка, состоящая не более чем из 20 символов;
>   <Должность> - строка, состоящая не более чем из 15 символов;
>   <Стаж> <Оклад> <Премия> - целые числа.
>
> Под стажем понимается количество полных лет, отработанных сотрудником
>   в данной организации. Оклад и премия - целые числа, не превышающие 1
>   000 000.   Эти элементы входной строки отделены друг от друга одним
>   пробелом. Пример входной строки:
>
> ```
> Иванов механик 15 25500 5000
> ```
>
> Требуется написать программу, которая будет выводить на экран фамилии,
>   должности и стаж трёх сотрудников с наибольшей зарплатой. Если среди
>   остальных есть сотрудники, с такой же зарплатой, что и один из этих
>   трёх, то следует также вывести и их фамилии, должности и стаж.
>   Зарплата сотрудника равна сумме его оклада и премии.

Решаю задачу на Паскале (других языков не знаю). Работаю по следующему принципу: считываю строки в цикле от 1 до N. Затем в процедуре Disturb разбиваю эти строки на соответствующие ячейки массивов. Процедура работает - проверял. Когда n равно 1, 2 всё нормально. Когда n=3 и больше программа прекращает своё выполнение с ошибкой №201. К чему я не так обращаюсь? Просьба не переделывать мой ход решения.

```
Var    
        data, name, dol: Array[1..1000] of String;
        sta, zar: Array[1..1000] of Integer;
        n, i, j, max1, max2, max3, index: Integer;

Procedure Disturb;
Var
    t: string;
    t1, t2: Integer;
Begin
    index := pos(' ', data[i]);
        name[i] := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
        Delete(data[i], 1, index);

        index := pos(' ', data[i]);
        dol[i] := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
        Delete(data[i], 1, index);

        index := pos(' ', data[i]);
        t := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
        Val(t, sta[i]);
        Delete(data[i], 1, index);

        index := pos(' ', data[i]);
        t := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
        Val(t, t1);
        Delete(data[i], 1, index);

        t := copy(data[i], 1, Length(data[i]));
        Val(t, t2);
        zar[i] := t1+t2;
End;



Begin
        Readln(n);
        For i := 1 to n do
                Readln(data[i]);
        For i := 1 to n do
                Begin
                      Disturb;  
                End;
        max1 := 0;
        max2 := 0;
        max3 := 0;
End.
```

Почему ошибку выдает? Где я обращаюсь не несуществующей ячейке или что не так?

---

доделал программу. вот финальный вариант:

```
Var
  data, name, dol: Array[1..1000] of String;
  sta, zar: Array[1..1000] of LongInt;
  n, i, j, max1, max2, max3, index: LongInt;

Procedure Disturb;
Var
  t: string;
  t1, t2, err: LongInt;
Begin
  index := pos(' ', data[i]);
  name[i] := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
  Delete(data[i], 1, index);

  index := pos(' ', data[i]);
  dol[i] := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
  Delete(data[i], 1, index);

  index := pos(' ', data[i]);
  t := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
  Val(t, sta[i], err);
  Delete(data[i], 1, index);

  index := pos(' ', data[i]);
  t := copy(data[i], 1, index-1);
  Val(t, t1, err);
  Delete(data[i], 1, index);

  t := copy(data[i], 1, Length(data[i]));
  Val(t, t2, err);
  zar[i] := t1+t2;
End;

Begin 
  Readln(n);

  For i := 1 to n do
    Readln(data[i]);
  For i := 1 to n do
    Disturb;

  max1 := 0;
  max2 := 0;
  max3 := 0;

  for i := 1 to n do
    if (max1 < zar[i]) then
      max1:=zar[i];

  for i := 1 to n do
    if ((max2 < zar[i]) and (zar[i] < max1)) then
      max2 := zar[i];
  for i := 1 to n do
    if ((max3 <zar[i]) and (zar[i] < max2)) then
      max3 := zar[i];

  for i := 1 to n do
    if (zar[i] = max1) then
      writeln(name[i], ' ', dol[i], ' ', sta[i]);

  for i := 1 to n do
    if (zar[i] = max2) then
      writeln(name[i], ' ', dol[i], ' ', sta[i]);

  for i := 1 to n do
    if (zar[i] = max3) then
      writeln(name[i], ' ', dol[i], ' ', sta[i]);

  Readln;
End.
```

ответьте пожалуйста: правильное решение?

Comment: Конечно я не специалист. Но почему бы не производить считывание сразу и в структуру? После будет удобнее сортировать по зарплате всю структуру, нежели 5 отдельных массивов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, почему у вас функция val имеет только два параметра, когда их там три?

Преобразовывает строковое значение в его числовое представление.

> Объявление:  Procedure Val(S; Var V;
> Var Code : Integer);   Где:   S    -
> переменная со строковым типом. Должна
> представлять
>          последовательность символов, формирующих знаковое целое число.   V 
> - переменная типа Real или Integer   Code - переменная типа Integer
>
> Режим: Windows,  Protected,  Real
>
> Замечания: Преобразовывает строковое
> значение (S) в его числовое
> представление, как это происходит при
> чтении из текстового файла с помощью
> Read. Code - позиция, в которой
> произошла ошибка при преобразовании,
> или нуль, если ошибки не было.

Во-вторых типа Integer (в 16-ти битной системе это всего лишь 2^16-1 = 32767) не достаточно для вашей задачи, используйте для зарплаты тип Longint.

Проверил программу, работает замечательно. Хотя, вы должны понимать, если структура файла будет ложная, тогда у вас будут ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка 201 [возникает](http://bpascal.ru/doc/error.php?p=5&number=201)
при возникновении одной из следующих ситуаций: индексное выражение массива находилось вне допустимого диапазона;

Знать бы еще на какую строчку ругается тогда можно было бы сказать где выход за пределы.
Я паскаль плохо знаю так что беглым взглядом не скажу где ошибка, хотя судя по тому как вы в процедуре используете глобальные переменные видимо, где то там и ошибка.